# Am I failed and being ignored?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am currently applying for a doctoral student position (fall term 2022) in some university. The application procedure is somehow "manual". I submitted my documents to an appointed contact person and then the contact person will forward them to a potential professor. An interested professor then will submit a formal application to the admission committee which has the final words on whether the applicant is admitted or not. I've been informed that there is a professor who is willing to be my supervisor (I don't know who), so I assume my application is on the committee's table. It is now almost a year since my application was formally submitted and I still don't know if it's successful or failed. I have sent an inquiry to the contact person regarding the status of my application but my email is unanswered. I start to think that I have failed and only successful applicants are informed. Is it a common practice for a grad school to ignore unsuccessful applicants?

Comment: It is impossible to say. Only that university can answer.

Comment: I think this is an unusual enough process that we cannot say. I would recommend you check and see if there is a second person you can cc on your email communication. It is possible the contact from more than a year ago (if a staff person) changed jobs.

Comment: According to the website, it is the same person